# How to make a 3-bit full adder using only half adders

Tags: electronics, digital-communication

I've been trying to solve this question but I don't know the right answer.[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far ? do you have a gate level diagram of the half adder and the full adder ? Please add both to the question. If the full adder requires an XOR gate, the XOR gates from multiple half adders can be used. etc...

Comment: [Homework](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121/what-should-our-position-be-on-homework-type-questions) sounding questions require your efforts to solve it be shown in the question itself.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a [homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: I've tried and I got 6 half adders to make a 3 bit full adder, I just wanted confirmation.